# Trying to insert a sheets chart in line into an email draft using Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I am trying to insert a sheets chart in line into an email draft using Google Sheets Script.  My script creates a PNG of the chart, but only attaches it instead of inserting it inline.  Can someone shed some light as to what I have wrong in my script?

```
var chartBlobs = new Array(charts.length); 
var emailBody = "Charts<br>";
var emailImages = {};
for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
  var builder = charts[i].modify();
  builder.setOption('vAxis.format', '#');
  var newchart = builder.build();
  chartBlobs[i] = newchart.getAs('image/png');
  emailBody = emailBody + "<p align='center'><img src='cid:chart" + i + "'></p>";
  emailImages["chart" + i] = chartBlobs[i];
}

//var htmltable =[];
var TABLEFORMAT = 'cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" dir="ltr" border="0" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;font-size:12pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:0px solid#ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;'
var htmltable = '<table ' + TABLEFORMAT + ' ">';

for (row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
  htmltable += '<tr>';
  for (col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
    if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + '' + '</td>';} 
    else if (row === 0)  {
      htmltable += '<th>' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
    }
    else if (row === 6)  {
      htmltable += '<th>' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
    }
    else if (row === 8)  {
      htmltable += '<th><font color=#3A8FDD>' + data[row][col] + '</font></th>';
    }
    else {htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
  }
  htmltable += '</tr>';
}
htmltable += '</table>';
Logger.log(data);
Logger.log(htmltable);

//Send Email
GmailApp.createDraft(emails, subject, '', {
  htmlBody: htmltable, 
  inlineImages: emailImages
});
```

Comment: Same result.  Picture was sent as an attachment.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work either smh thanks for the help

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1stxuJnIbFHVWgS1MG_sDIYPUtXaf4n0N/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the inlineImage reference in the htmlBody. But, You're only sending `htmlTable` instead of `emailBody`. Try

```
GmailApp.createDraft(emails, subject, '', {
  htmlBody: emailBody+htmltable,  //Added
  inlineImages: emailImages
});
```